# Can you make the "share" box actually wide enough to fit URLs?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, sharing

This is a daily occurrence as I use StackExchange.  Hit "Share..." Get the popup box, then struggle to select the entire URL.

[image]

*While there may be iOS issues here, **the point is the share textbox is intentionally too small to fit the URL.***

And SE URLs are reasonably tinyfied, and of known size, which makes this undersizing rather senseless.  It's like *gating* to exclude or frustrate mobile devices.

> Here in iOS 9, you can drag the text box to the right, and it will even select invisible characters where they would be if the box were larger... Sometimes that works, but if you go 1px too far, it closes the selection area entirely and you must start over.

For my most copied URLs, I have taken to memorizing the last 3 digits of the URL and typing it in by hand.

Comment: I've not had issues clicking in the box, choosing "select all" and then "copy". Do you not get that "select all" option? Worth noting, that box is exactly the width of my iPhone, so making it any bigger would be problematic.

Comment: As you can see, "select all" is simply not offered.   It is not in the list above, nor is it in the icon tray.  I *have* seen it, but I rarely see it. 95% of the time it is exactly this.

Comment: It won't appear if you've selected some of the content. You have to just have the cursor in the box. Regardless, having a "copy" button (if that works in iOS) as part of the modal is probably the better/easier solution.

Comment: Yeah, I often place the cursor in the box.  I get the cursor in the box, tray icons of undo, redo and paste.. And no "above box" at all.  I know the `Select Select-all Copy` "above box" of which you speak, it is just very, very shy.

Answer (score 13):

I agree that this should be widened - the URLs are not excessively long, we should be able to show the whole thing.

There's a more subtle problem with this, BTW: it obscures the fact that your user ID is on the end of that URL. I know a fairly experienced *moderator* who got tripped up by that recently!

This probably worked just fine in the old days when post IDs, user IDs, and textbox padding were all smaller.

Comment: Is removing the user id there not the easiest way to fix this particular aspect of the issue? I've made that mistake myself and copied a link that identified my SE account in a context where I don't want to reveal it. This would break the badges that rely on this information, but I don't think they're worth the trouble anyway.

Comment: Well... That might be worth doing, but there's no way that retiring three badges is *easier* than increasing a width.

Comment: It's not the easier fix, but a more complete and reliable one for the information leak aspect. Removing the user id was status-declined by Jeff around 8 years ago, I was mostly wondering if it's worth bringing it up again.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE 2022**

The URL is now auto-selected when you open the Share box. You can either hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or similar) or use the "Copy link" button to copy the URL.

On desktop/laptop:

> [image]

On mobile (after pressing "Copy link"):

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest an alternative: What about a "copy" button that does the copying job automatically? It'd be even more convenient for both desktop and mobile users.

Comment: I hate how it’s a free form text area! On desktop I often overwrite the entire thing by accidentally pressing space...

Comment: @Laurel On desktop I just right-click the "share" text and click "copy link", without even letting the text form show up.

Answer (score 5):

We've made a few changes to the Share dialog box since this request was made. There is now a "Copy link" option, and the link is auto-highlighted as well. As such, I've updated the status to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Hello! FYI, @ mentions don't work in answers, so to ping Harper, you'd need to leave a comment on the question. IIRC, editing it to [tag:status-completed] also pings the OP. Also, you need to do `[tag:status-completed]` not just `[status-completed]` in your answer for it to render correctly as a tag. Welcome to Meta, though!

Comment: Thank you @cocomac! Will remember to format the tag properly for next time.

Comment: Is it possible that change made the Share button disappear completely (on Safari 14, other browsers still have it for me)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Do you have any screenshots you can provide? Or a link to the question where the Share button is missing?

Comment: I have: https://imgur.com/yyZh2Ew Note: this is for me, when logged in, on Safari, since a few days I noticed (using the feature sporadically), on every post (there are no more share buttons at all), yet, a quick check in other browsers shows it should be there and is in them, just not my main SE browser…

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot! I will check on my end to see if I can reproduce this issue. Are you experiencing this issue on Safari for a few other SE sites? I want to understand if it's specific to Safari and on a particular SE site (MSE in this instance) or if it affects others too.

Comment: It happens only in Safari 14 (Firefox, Chrome, Orion, Brave, Vivaldi… all 'clean'), even with all (blocking) extensions made sure as off/disabled, whether logged  in or not; but on all SE sites I tried: this one, +Skeptics, History, Askubuntu.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the information @LаngLаngС. It might be specific to that version of Safari. On my end, I am on version 15.4 and I have the Share option available: https://i.imgur.com/djWg165.png. I can go ahead and create a bug ticket for now.